# TFS + a com project + a .net project

Tags: tfs

We currently have an application that is in two peices.

One is a c++ solution that complies down to a com assembly.
The other solution is our .net app that refrences the com assembly.

We've had a rather unstructured process for building the com assebly and distributing it to the developers working on the .net side.

I'd like to streamline this processes. I'm trying to find a way to automate the whole processes with TFS-2010, I'd love to be able to kick off a build that ends up with an installer created for the testers.

Is the answer to merget the two solutions into a single one?
Any guidence on managing this would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can point to multiple solutions in a build so merging the solutions isn't necessary. In your build definition, go to the process tab and choose the solutions you want to build. I think you'll need to set the build type to Release - Mixed Platforms.

Packaging could be handled by WiX (3.5), although you might want to create 2 installers depending on how closely coupled the applications are.